# How to sort an array of objects with two keys in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I want to sort it based on two keys.

```
var data = [{COMPONENT: 'PM-ABC', PRIORITY: '0.35'},
            {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '0.35'}
            {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: ''}]
```

It should first sort on key COMPONENT (Ascending order) and then on PRIORITY ('' should come before number say '0.35')

I have tried below code which sorts based on only key i.e COMPONENT

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a['COMPONENT'] > b['COMPONENT']) ? 1 : (a['COMPONENT'] < b['COMPONENT']) ? -1 : 0;
        });
```

I am expecting below result

```
data = [{COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: ''}
        {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '0.35'}
        {COMPONENT: 'PM-ABC', PRIORITY: '0.35'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
let data = [{COMPONENT: 'PM-ABC', PRIORITY: '0.35'},
            {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '0.35'},
            {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: ''}];
data.sort((a,b) => a.COMPONENT.localeCompare(b.COMPONENT) ||
  a.PRIORITY.localeCompare(b.PRIORITY));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the most basic way and without doing the sort strategy depending on some query upfront, you can just have a sort callback that first takes into account the property `COMPONENT`, when they are different, then property `PRIORITY` and only in the end the equality returning zero.

The point being that if `COMPONENT` don't differ, the first two criteria are passed and the third becomes the next property comparison.

```js
var data = [
  {COMPONENT: 'PM-ABC', PRIORITY: '0.35'},
  {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '0.35'},
  {COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: ''}
]

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.COMPONENT < b.COMPONENT) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.COMPONENT > b.COMPONENT) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.PRIORITY < b.PRIORITY) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.PRIORITY > b.PRIORITY) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by stages, first `COMPONENT` and then `PRIORITY` with a check.

```js
const
    data = [{ COMPONENT: 'PM-ABC', PRIORITY: '0.35' }, { COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '0.35' }, { COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '' }];

data.sort((a, b) =>
    a.COMPONENT.localeCompare(b.COMPONENT) ||
    (b.PRIORITY === '') - (a.PRIORITY === '')
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `PRIORITY` is expected to be a number and that an empty string `''` is the same as `0`, your solution would be:

```
const data = [{ COMPONENT: 'PM-ABC', PRIORITY: '0.35' }, { COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '0.35' }, { COMPONENT: 'PM', PRIORITY: '' }];

data.sort((a, b) => 
    a.COMPONENT.localeCompare(b.COMPONENT) ||
    ((parseFloat(a.PRIORITY) || 0) - (parseFloat(b.PRIORITY) || 0))
);

console.log(data);
```